# Вернуть значение из cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Добрый день.
Есть у меня на сайте блок, в котором находится ещё несколько блоков.

```
<div class="asd">
 <div class="s1 active"></div>
 <div class="s2"></div>
 <div class="s3"></div>
 <div class="s4"></div>
</div>
```

(блок **s1** "по дефолту" использует **active**)
При нажатии на один из этих блоков нужно добавить ему класс **active** и сохранить в **cookie**.. Я это сделал, но вот как при загрузки страницы вернуть **active** выбранному блоку?

Вот код который я использую сейчас:

```
$('.asd div').on('click', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault()
 $('.asd div').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 setCookie('ASD_S', 1, 365);
});
```

Comment: что за функция setCookie?

Comment: @Grundy, создаёт куки.

Comment: ты ее писал? это библиотечная функция? откуда-то просто взял ее код?

Comment: кроме того, непонятно что именно ты сохраняешь в куки, и как по этой информации ты можешь узнать какому элементу надо выставить active

Comment: @Grundy, она используется у меня в одном коде, выглядит она так.  `if(getCookie('wCookieLook')) {$('#cookie').addClass('active');};  
$('#cookie').click(function(){setCookie('wCookieLook', 1, 365);}); `

Comment: Не понял, как этот комментарий отвечает хотя бы на один из трех вопросов

Comment: @Grundy, вы спросили "что за функция setCookie", я ответил.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47034/discussion-between-grundy-and-cbipok2513).

Comment: Куки гоняются на сервер при каждом запросе. Не стоит хранить в них информацию, которая там(на сервере) не нужна. Используйте `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут в ответах в редакторе хранилище работать не будет, но у себя можете запустить и проверить.
Я не использую jquery поэтому можете заменить некоторые участки кода на свои, если надо. 
По комментариям думаю все поймете.

```js
  $('.asd div').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   $('.asd div').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   // Записываем класс, который активен
  localStorage["active"] = this.classList[0];
  });


    // Проверяем, есть ли в локальном хранилище значение по ключу active
    if ( localStorage.getItem('active') != null ) {
        // Если ключ есть, то достаем из хранилища записанный класс и присваиваем ему active
        document.querySelector("." + localStorage.getItem('active')).classList.add("active");
    } else {
        // Если ключа нет, то классу s1 добавляем класс active
        document.querySelector(".s1").classList.add("active");
    }
```

```css
  .active {
   color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="asd">
 <div class="s1">345345</div>
 <div class="s2">35345</div>
 <div class="s3">345435</div>
 <div class="s4">345435</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать объект [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie), который при чтении возвращает строку, содержащую все куки со значениями, разделёнными точками с запятой и пробелом:

```
MyCookie=somevalue; AnotherCookie=anothervalue; SomethingStrange=surprise;...
```

Для выделения нужной куки можно использовать split, как показано вот в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730362/get-cookie-by-name#15724300, который отлично находится гуглом по запросу "javascript get value of cookie".

В куке сохраняем идентификатор (или базовый класс) элемента, потом функцию `getCookie()` вызываем из `document.onload()` и устанавливаем класс в 'active'. Для облегчения задачи, можно пользоваться не getGookie, а использовать пакет [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/latest) и тогда весь код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<script src="js/js.cookie.js"></script>

...

function activate_s(obj) {
    var thisclass = obj.attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    alert('activating '+obj.attr('class'));
    $('.asd div').removeClass('active');
    obj.addClass('active');
    Cookies.set('ASD_S', thisclass);
}

$('.asd div').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked on '+$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
        activate_s($(this));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
        alert(Cookies.get('ASD_S'));
        if(Cookies.get('ASD_S')) {
                activate_s($('.asd div.'+Cookies.get('ASD_S')));
        }
});
```

Comment: стоит добавить код из ответа по ссылке

Comment: Мне б разжевать.. А то голова не хочет работать..

Comment: @Grundy, категорически не согласен. Это напрямую нарушает идею веба как гиперлинковой системы. Дублирование информации не несёт никакой пользы. Только увеличение энтропии. Тем более, что в исходном посте могут появляться какие-то ценные правки и комментарии, которые сюда никто переносить не будет. Copy-pase - это зло. Всегда.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, а чего тут жевать? Вызваешь функцию getCookie(), описанную по ссылку, с именем искомой куки в качестве параметра. Если значение устраивает, вызываешь addClass. Весь этот код засовываешь в window.onload или document.onload.

Comment: Так как enSO и ruSO это разные сайты, и нельзя вопрос на одном закрыть как дубликат вопроса на другом, нельзя в ответе дать одну ссылку. [Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1805/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F). Кроме же информации по ссылке, в текущем ответе нет ответа на вопрос. Кроме того, вы можете перевести исходные вопрос/ответ и пометить данный вопрос как дубликат.

Comment: @Grundy, добавил пример работающего кода с использованием JS Cookie. Теперь ответ - это не только ссылка.

Comment: _sidenote:_ а вы знаете, что `$('.asd div').on('click',` в данном случае то же самое что и `$('.asd div').click(`?

Comment: @AlexanderAmelkin то есть, ваш идеал Веба это сеть, в которой любая информация существует лишь в одном экземпляре, а остальные на неё лишь ссылаются? ...и когда первоисточник исчезает, доступ к этой информации теряют **вообще все**? Нормы качества ответов у нас не с потолка возникли.

Comment: @AlexanderAmelkin Если вам не хочется писать полный ответ - вы можете (в следующий раз) привести ссылку в комментарии к вопросу. А у ответов на этом сайте есть утвержденные на Мете нормы качества.

Comment: @D-side, честно говоря, полагаю неуместным разводить тут подобный спор, но 3NF - это в рамках одной БД (или одного проекта) почти всегда хорошо. С моей точки зрения SO - это один проект, как бы не назывались его части. Но если формальные правила диктуют copy-paste, то я не могу сделать ничего иного, кроме как подчиниться им и прошу прощения за невольное нарушение.

Comment: @AlexanderAmelkin проект действительно один, но это не означает, что делать внутренние ссылки безопасно. Вопросы могут удаляться без предупреждения. И это не формальное правило, это обоснованный консенсус сообщества, которым многие здесь пользуются при голосовании за и против ответов. Вам кроме минусов на ответ за это ничего толком не грозило :)

Comment: @AlexanderAmelkin, поставишь Ваш код, при загрузке страницы все .asd div имеют класс active.

Comment: _но 3NF - это в рамках одной БД_ - но ведь на каждом сайте своя db. Кстати говоря, всегда можно спросить про это на [meta]

Answer (score -1):

```
//Это функция вернет значение cookie
function cookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
};

//Пример:
var asd = cookie("ASD_S");
```